# multi language List view sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, multilingual

Hi I am creating a new site collection to my organization and i want to add News list which will contain news in both languages English and Arabic

I create a new list then i Add column such as

```
Title_en,Title_en,Details_ar,Details_en,...
```

then i created two views **Arview** for Arabic and **Enview** for English which will show the news in default page

now after i add webpart to the default page for English site I selected **Enview** then I changed the language to Arabic and modify the View to **Arview** (as what we do in page title) but that did not work it keeps one view for both Arabic and English site

what is the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

" then I changed the language to Arabic " where did you change this? Are talking about language and region setting of user?

Why are you expecting your webpart to change depending on the user language setting, as its a single page you are referring to. You might need to use some script to detect user language and change/hide webpart on runtime.

Please help me understand, if I have missed something.

Comment: if there is a script that can be added to the site to hide webpart depend on user language please provide it to me